# how to pass a string from asp to C# Form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mutex, semaphore

Is there a way to pass an string from web appication to form? 
For example:
    asp: Onclick = "i am ready to send"
    C# Form : On wait status for receive string from asp

i have try to search on semaphore but so far can only use on single program can't pass thread for another program.
Can anyone give some comment about this?
Thank you.

Comment: you mean in webform ?

Comment: @Usman is in Web application

Comment: can provide code of webpage and form?

Comment: @Usman something like this
<asp:Button id="bttn" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="Bttn_Click"/>
about form is using wait state

Comment: so you want to get the value of text in the .cs file of the webpage?

Comment: @Usman yes need to get the value from .cs

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about Windows Forms, it's obviously not possible to send it directly, since the Forms are run as a Windows application, but the Webpages are run based on IIS, and it's a web server.

There might be some solutions which are not recommended though. Like triggering something inside windows kernel, which a windows forms app might have an access. But web forms have a huge limitations, and your only way to send an information is to create a network connection.

Comment: is web application, what you mean is create an socket connection in web and one in form?

Comment: Yes, socket connection, http connection, WCF, Web Services.. You name it. But it always means that you send information through internet, not directly from one app to another. Or you can create a simple Sql Server, or you can write a simple text file for your webpage to read it.

Answer (score 0):

The most newbie thing you can do is : Connect the ASP and C# form to a database,insert the string into the database and then take it from the database in c# form. It's not so optimal or whatsoever but it might help you until you find another way